# Custom post type is_singular condtional not working when managing sidebar display

Tags: custom-post-types, php, templates, conditional-tags

I am using the `if ( is_home() || ! is_page_template( array( 'template-investment.php', 'template-tourism.php' ) ) || ! is_singular( 'listing' ) ) {` conditional to control the display of the theme's sidebar in certain instances on my client's theme.

It is working for the `is_home` and `! is_page_template` conditionals, but not the `is_singular` for the listing custom post type (Toolset plugin).

The body classes for the single listing pages are included below.

```
listing-template-default
single
single-listing
postid-3119
logged-in
views-template-content-template-for-listings
```

As `single-listing` is included, I would assume it should be working.

Would the dynamic nature of how Toolset creates templates be causing conflict?

**Update**

The sidebar should not be displayed on single post pages that are using the **listing** custom post type.

Comment: What result are you after? Your condition is checking if it’s not a particular page template OR it’s not a singular listing. That condition will always be true.

Comment: @JacobPeattie The sidebar should **not** be displayed on single post pages using the **listing** custom post type.

Comment: Ok, did you see the rest of my comment? is_singular is working fine, your logic is just incorrect. At least one of your ORs needs to be an AND.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the if conditional using suggestions from Jacob Peattie and the following fixed my issues.

```
if ( ! is_page_template( array( 'template-investment.php', 'template-tourism.php' ) ) && ! is_tax( 'listings' ) && ! is_singular( 'listing' ) ) {
```

The result correctly removed the sidebar.php from loading its code on specific templates, taxonomy, and single post type.